# How to make JS work on dynamically created table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Problem: How do I make a function work on rows created after initial page load?

On page load my code fetches data from a Mongo DB and creates table rows for each entry with a `for (item of data)` loop. When this is done, some code is run that makes all the just created rows clickable and expandable. It works well. This is the code:

```
$('tbody tr').not('.hidden-row').on('click', function(event){ 
            $('tbody tr.opentr').not(this).removeClass('opentr') 
            $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('opentr')  
            var hiddenRow = $(this).next(".hidden-row")
            var rowExists = $(hiddenRow).length
        if (rowExists) { 
            $('tbody .hidden-row').not(hiddenRow).hide()
            $(hiddenRow).toggle()                        
            } else { 
            var expRowContent = $(this).find('.hide').html()
            var newExpRow = '<tr class="hidden-row" style="display:none;"><td colspan="7">' + expRowContent + '</td></tr>'
            $(newExpRow).insertAfter(this)
            $('tbody .hidden-row').not(hiddenRow).hide()
            $(this).next('.hidden-row').toggle()
            }
        })
```

All good. Now the user triggers the adding of a new row which is inserted at the end of the table. Works fine.

But this row is not clickable, because the code above binds to the elements that were created when it was run.

If I simply run the code again, my dynamically added row is now clickable and expandable. Great — except for the fact that for some reason this makes all the already created rows **not** clickable. Only the just created row is now clickable.

I have been digging into the console but can't see any code changes to the existing rows that would explain this. Why it that? And should this be approached in a different way?

Comment: Go read up on the keyword _event delegation_.

Comment: [Event delegation explanation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/), and more [jQuery-related page](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 0):

The comments have advised Event delegation. Here's an example:

```
// add the event listener to the entire table body
$('table tbody').on('click', (evt)=>
    /* Check if the target is a <tr> or a descendant of <tr>
    if(evt.target.matches('tr') || evt.target.matches('tr *')) {
       // ... your old event listener code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried giving you an upvote, but I am too new to Stackoverflow, it seems. After some more research I found that this, shorter, code does the same trick: 

// Original: $('tbody tr').not('.hidden-row').on('click', function(event)  
// New: $('tbody').not('.hidden-row').on('click', 'tr', function(event) 

// I basically just moved the 'tr' from the target and made it the second argument in the listener instead.

Comment: Hi, you've discovered the simplest solution, the optional 2nd argument of `on`, the `descendantFilteringSelector`.